# php curl for datadog api

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, datadog

i am trying to write a php curl for datadog api,but it return internal error. this was working in bash script but throwing error while converting in phpcurl. can someone help me on this.

```
$data = [
    'tags' =>  '[env:prod]'

];
    $headers = [
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ];
     $tagUrl="https://app.datadoghq.com/api/v1/tags/hosts/".$host."?api_key=".$api_key."&application_key=".$app_key;

        $http_method='POST';
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tagUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
        $out=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: If you are getting `internal error 500` then there's nothing to do with your code, it is a server side error unless you are doing something wrong. Please refer to datadog.

Comment: its showing just internal error, not internal error 500. @Ahmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you're using to send the data does not comply with the [documentation](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=console#tags-update) and your call fails to complete.

The call would work if you change your `$data` to:

```
$data = [ 'tags' => ['env:prod'] ];
```

Agreed that the error returned by the API is not really helpful, filed an issue in Datadog to correct that  behavior and return the proper error code and not a 500 (it's actually a 500 and you can see it by printing `curl_getinfo($ch)` after you executed your curl session).

Comment: i just fixed the issue by adding this line. $data = array('tags'=> array('env:non-production'));